# Detect heap corruption

Tags: c++, visual-c++, memory-management, windbg

Does visual studio 2008 has any options (run time) to detect immedidate detection of heap corruption?

Comment: Windows does.  Vista has an excellent heap allocator, also available in Win7.  It automatically invokes a debugger break when it detects corruption and sees a debugger attached.  Kept me out of trouble for the past 3 years.

Answer (score 2):

If you look through the list of [Debug Routines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1666sb98%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) exported from the Visual C++ debug runtime, you can find many useful debugging functions, including [_CrtSetDbgFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5at7yxcs%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that can be used to set how often the debug heap checks itself for corruption.

Answer (score 1):

Application Verifier from Microsoft is an excellent tool for this purpose. I've found it very useful. Download it :

```
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20028
```

And then look around for some tutorial. Usually just point to your executable, then run your exe in Visual Studio debug as always. It should break near where the issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You can activate the 'Full Page Heap' on any windows (since Windows 2000 at least !), with the release build of your application.
It will catch 99% of errors at the time they occur.
You can look at this [page](http://www.devproconnections.com/article/net-framework2/debug-heap-issues-with-full-page-heap-129771) for an tutorial of this functionality.
Don't forget to deactivate full page heap when you are done troubleshooting your application.
This technique may not work on a debug build, since the debug version of the CRT uses its own scheme to allocate dynamic memory.